# django : How to use signals?

Tags: python, django

After creating a user account with this model:

```py
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

The form:

```py
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", 
                  "username", "email", "password1", "password2")
        model = get_user_model()
```

I want an default entry into another model from another application yet in the same project

```py
class History(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    earned_leave = models.IntegerField(default = 10)
    casual_leave = models.IntegerField(default = 10)
    sick_leave = models.IntegerField(default = 10)
    paid_leave =models.IntegerField(default = 10)
```

where employee_ID is the username and name is the first_name.

I have tried using a signal but I have no idea how to send the values into the database.

```py
def send_data(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('data sent') 

post_save.connect(receiver = send_data, sender= User)
```

Instead of this print statement what should I write in order to send the code into History table in the database. I'm working on a human management system.

Comment: With your updated code, does it still print the `data sent` message?

Comment: @WillKeeling no it's not printing

Comment: It's not a good idea to re-write your question after you have accepted an answer - it can be unfair on people who answered your original question, and fewer people will look at your question after it has been accepted.

Comment: @Alasdair Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its too simple. you can write your saving history code here:

```
def send_data(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    from your_app.models import History
    history = History()
    history.employee_ID = instance.username
    history.name = instance.first_name
    ....
    history.save()
```

Comment: I've put the above code in my models.py, yet on creating a new user the history table isn't getting updated.

Comment: where you write your signal file?

Comment: in models.py of accounts application

Comment: does post_save imported from correct path? `from django.db.models.signals impor post_save`

Comment: Django updates the `User.last_login field` [every time the user logs in](https://github.com/django/django/blob/570402ffd7efd529eb597d86525b80a6fbfca0e7/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L14). If you only want to create the `History` instance when the user is created, then check `if created:` in your signal handler.