# Django : User account creation with two different models

Tags: python, django

disclaimer : I've gone through the django - documentation, but didn't come to a conclusion.

I was handed over a project of my senior in college to work on with. 
In an application in the project: `accounts` - obviously it's to create user accounts.

in models.py

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

though in the forms.py this model was not used. forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "username", "email", "password1", "password2")
        model = get_user_model()
```

But here the imported model is something other than the defined model in models.py, rather he imported the model from `from django.contrib.auth`

So I've tried to comment out the model from the models.py and migrate, it yields an error.

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error`

rather instead of `model = get_user_model` I've used

`model = User` (from models.py)

even this yield's error `unable to import User`

Could anyone please explain me what's the relation and why should I use both the models?? Since the senior is no more, I've no chance of contacting him.

Tracebacks - 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 150, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 318, in remove_field
    self._remake_table(model, delete_field=field)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 265, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 296, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error`

Comment: Please include the full tracebacks in your question. The [`get_user_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) helper is covered in the docs - it imports the model defined by `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.

Comment: Subclassing `class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):` is a very unusual approach. [Normally](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) you would subclass `AbstractUser`. However, [switching the user model for an existing project is very tricky](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project), so you might not be able to change it now.

Comment: *rather he imported the model from from `django.contrib.auth`* - I'm not sure what you mean by this. Neither user model is imported in the code you show. Instead, the `get_user_model` method is imported, and then that is called.

Comment: if he imported the model, what was the use of creating one in models.py which was never used? @Alasdair

Comment: Why do you think the one in `models.py` is never used? It sounds like `AUTH_USER_MODEL` points to that model, so `get_user_model()` imports it.

Comment: @Alasdair where do you get to see it ? let me point to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177182/django-how-to-use-signals question which was the root cause of the current question.

Comment: Where do you get to see what?

Comment: @Alasdair How did you come to a conclusion that 'It sounds like AUTH_USER_MODEL points to that model, so get_user_model() imports it.'

Comment: In Django, you [define a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) by setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings. If the custom `User` model was not being used, then deleting it wouldn't be causing you issues.

Comment: @Alasdair I didn't find it in my settings.py

Comment: If `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is not being set then I can't tell what's going on. If this is a new project, then I would delete your migrations, [define the custom user model properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) and set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, then generate new migrations. If it's an existing project then it's going to be trickier to resolve the issue, and I'm afraid I can't help with that.